# How to convert xml string in given format to json?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

When i try to read xml data from Ajax response

xmlDoc = data[0].body;
alert(xmlDoc);

i got below string of xml string

```
"&lt;VNET&gt;&lt;ID&gt;0&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;UID&gt;0&lt;/UID&gt;&lt;GID&gt;0&lt;/GID&gt;&lt;UNAME&gt;oneadmin&lt;/UNAME&gt;&lt;GNAME&gt;oneadmin&lt;/GNAME&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;vnet&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;PERMISSIONS&gt;&lt;OWNER_U&gt;1&lt;/OWNER_U&gt;&lt;OWNER_M&gt;1&lt;/OWNER_M&gt;&lt;OWNER_A&gt;0&lt;/OWNER_A&gt;&lt;GROUP_U&gt;0&lt;/GROUP_U&gt;&lt;GROUP_M&gt;0&lt;/GROUP_M&gt;&lt;GROUP_A&gt;0&lt;/GROUP_A&gt;&lt;OTHER_U&gt;0&lt;/OTHER_U&gt;&lt;OTHER_M&gt;0&lt;/OTHER_M&gt;&lt;OTHER_A&gt;0&lt;/OTHER_A&gt;&lt;/PERMISSIONS&gt;&lt;CLUSTER_ID&gt;-1&lt;/CLUSTER_ID&gt;&lt;CLUSTER&gt;&lt;/CLUSTER&gt;&lt;TYPE&gt;0&lt;/TYPE&gt;&lt;BRIDGE&gt;bro&lt;/BRIDGE&gt;&lt;VLAN&gt;0&lt;/VLAN&gt;&lt;PHYDEV/&gt;&lt;VLAN_ID/&gt;&lt;GLOBAL_PREFIX/&gt;&lt;SITE_PREFIX/&gt;&lt;RANGE&gt;&lt;IP_START&gt;192.168.5.2&lt;/IP_START&gt;&lt;IP_END&gt;192.168.5.254&lt;/IP_END&gt;&lt;/RANGE&gt;&lt;TOTAL_LEASES&gt;0&lt;/TOTAL_LEASES&gt;&lt;TEMPLATE&gt;&lt;DNS&gt;&lt;![CDATA[192.168.5.1]]&gt;&lt;/DNS&gt;&lt;GATEWAY&gt;&lt;![CDATA[192.168.5.1]]&gt;&lt;/GATEWAY&gt;&lt;NETWORK_ADDRESS&gt;&lt;![CDATA[192.168.5.0]]&gt;&lt;/NETWORK_ADDRESS&gt;&lt;NETWORK_MASK&gt;&lt;![CDATA[255.255.255.0]]&gt;&lt;/NETWORK_MASK&gt;&lt;/TEMPLATE&gt;&lt;/VNET&gt;"
```

so to avoid Html parsing in javascript. I want actual xml formate string.

ex:

```
"&lt;VNET&gt;&lt;ID&gt;0&lt;/ID&gt;&lt;UID&gt;0&lt;/UID&gt;&lt;/VNET&gt;"
```

want like

```
"<VNET><ID>0</ID><UID>0</UID></VNET>"
```

Any One please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer would do what you're looking for, but it would be better to ensure the XML is not encoded in the original data response.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14227660/463205